# I'm trying to build a dice program using C++ it isn't displaying my return

Tags: c++, random

The code is printing the greeting and all the messages except the number. I need to see what is being generated by my random number generator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void greeting(int pnum){
       if(pnum == 1) {
           std::cout << "Please press \"ENTER\" to roll the die"; 
       }
       else {
            std::cout << "Please press \"ENTER\" to roll the die AGAIN"; 
       }
        std::cin.ignore();
}

int dieroll(void){
    int ran;
    srand(time(NULL));
    ran = rand()%6+1;
    std::cout << "You have rolled :" << std::endl;
    return ran;
}

int main(void){
    int counter, firstdie, ran;
    char firststart;

    do {
        greeting(1);
        firstdie = dieroll();
    }
 
    while (ran > 0);
    {
        return ran;
    }
    
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm a beginner so i'm unsure where to start trouble shooting. I'm looking into making local variables.

Comment: Are you expecting `std::cout << "You have rolled :" << std::endl;` to print the value of `ran`?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code. It will allow you to inspect the value of variables and step through the execution path. If you don't know how to use a debugger, this would be an excellent time to start learning. There's no  better tool in a coder's toolbox than the debugger, and it's never too early to start learning to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in main you do this

```
while (ran > 0);
{
    return ran;
}
```

First you never give 'ran' a value, so its either > 0, in which case you exit with a random completion code. Or 'ran' is <= 0, in which case you exit with a value of 0.

Its not clear what you are trying to do here, but either way your program terminates immediately

To be clear , a `return` in main will cause your program to stop immediatley

Then here

```
int dieroll(void){
    int ran;
    srand(time(NULL));
    ran = rand()%6+1;
    std::cout << "You have rolled :" << std::endl;
    return ran;
}
```

You intend to print 'ran' but in fact do not , you need

```
    std::cout << "You have rolled :" << ran << std::endl;
```

I wonder if you think that the 'ran' here is the same as the 'ran' in main, it is not, there is no relationship between them

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand what you meant in the first half of your explanation. I only added "while" because the code wouldn't run without it so I did it without fully understanding. Also, I managed to print the dice roll. Second half of the answer was what I needed. Thanks you so much

Comment: @SiDev take that while loop out - your program will run exactly the same. For sure not doing anything useful